# Почему наличие var при переопределении аргумента влияет на вызов функции, возвращающей этот аргумент?

Tags: javascript

```js
(function(x, f = () => x) {
  var x = 2;
  console.log(f());
})(1)
```

Простейший, казалось бы, код, который, по логике, должен вернуть **2**. Но возвращает он **1**.

Я считаю, что такое поведение было бы логично, если бы `f` было объявлено как:

1. *IIFE* вида `f = (() => x)()`
2. Простое присвоение вида `f = x`

В этих случаях значение `f` один раз посчиталось бы и было бы уже постоянным (понятно, что тогда `f` нельзя было бы вызвать как функцию, но сейчас не об этом).

Но, поскольку `f` - это функция, которая, как я считаю, должна выполняться по-разному в зависимости от значения `x`, то поведение кода для меня непонятно.

Я посчитал, что при вызове функция `f` вернет значение `x`, которое на данный момент уже равно **2** (переопределено строчкой выше). Но функция все равно возвращает **1**. Почему?

---

Методом проб и ошибок было выяснено, что если переопределить `f` в теле функции,

```js
(function(x, f = () => x) {
  f = () => x;
  var x = 2;
  console.log(f());
})(1)
```

то код начинает работать так, как я предполагал. Из чего делаю вывод, что решающим фактором здесь является *место*, в котором функция определена (а именно то, что она определена как значение по умолчанию для параметра). Но, опять же, почему это важно?

---

При написании этого вопроса я зашел еще дальше и выяснил также, что большую роль играет то, как переопределена `x`. Если код будет выглядеть так (без ключевого слова `var`),

```js
(function(x, f = () => x) {
  x = 2;
  console.log(f());
})(1)
```

то вывод снова логичен - **2**.

При этом первым делом я предположил, что, поскольку функция определена в строке аргументов (как значение по умолчанию), то она берет значение `x` не как значение переменной `x` в *теле функции*, а как значение `argument[0]`. Но ни при наличии `var`, ни при его отсутствии само значение `arguments[0]` не изменяется. А вот результат выполнения функции - да. Значит дело в чем-то другом. Вопрос только, в чем?

Comment: [в спецификации](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation)

Comment: @Grundy значит если присутствует хоть одно значение по умолчанию для параметра, то для все параметры относятся к одному EnvironmentRecord, а другие объявления - к другому?

Comment: @Grundy но я все равно не совсем понимаю, почему именно наличие `var` играет роль.

Comment: @Grundy а нет, кажется, начинаю понимать. Из за этого `var` `x` начинает относится к другому EnvironmentRecord, а при вызове функции значение `x` берется из другого EnvironmentRecord, который был создан для параметров? А он там по-прежнему равен 1, да?

Comment: Прикольный способ выстрелить себе в ногу

Comment: @AlexeyTen, это очень грустно, на самом деле, что о таких вещах вообще приходится задумываться. Боюсь представить, насколько такую ошибку сложно отловить

Comment: Ну, просто надо перестать пользоваться `var`. Если там написать `let`, то и нода и бабель ругаются на ошибку. Интересно ещё, что оригинальный код бабель транспилирует неправильно, но так как вы ожидали. http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=BQMwrgdgxgLglgewsAHgGgAQgwXg8ASlwD4MUiBvAKAwwDcBDAJzNwwCYBuGjKJAZwQAbAKYA6IQgDmoQgW4BfAsACMBIA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=latest%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0

Comment: О, в бабеле даже тикет есть сто лет https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4173

Comment: @AlexeyTen это просто пример из теста по ES6. Так что специально var я не использовал, но в целом вы правы. В общем, спасибо, буду иметь в виду

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос, почему вывод первого примера `1`, а не `2` кроется в формальных параметрах функции.

Текущая редакция (версия) спецификации описывает исполнение (точнее сказать инициализацию) функций в разделе [9.2.12 FunctionDeclarationInstantiation](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-functionexpressioninstantiation). В ней же прямым текстом сказано, что происходящее с [Лексическими Окружениями и их записями](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-lexical-environments) во время инициализации функции зависит от формальных параметров:

> When an execution context is established for evaluating an ECMAScript
>   function a new function Environment Record is created and bindings for
>   each formal parameter are instantiated in that Environment Record.
>   Each declaration in the function body is also instantiated. If the
>   function's formal parameters do not include any default value
>   initializers then the body declarations are instantiated in the same
>   Environment Record as the parameters. If default value parameter
>   initializers exist, a second Environment Record is created for the
>   body declarations. Formal parameters and functions are initialized as
>   part of FunctionDeclarationInstantiation. All other bindings are
>   initialized during evaluation of the function body.

В частности, если среди формальных параметров функции присутствует хотя бы один параметр, для которого определено значение по умолчанию (для краткости просто "параметр по умолчанию"), то для всех объявлений *внутри тела функции* создается *отдельное* Лексическое Окружение.

Именно по этой причине выражение `var x = 2` определяет **новую** переменную в специально созданном Лексическом Окружении.

Однако при этом, поскольку определение функции `f` относится к другому Лексическому Окружению (тому, которое было создано для формальных параметров), то при ее вызове будет взято то значение переменной `x`, которое записано в записи того Лексического Окружения, в котором определена функция `f`. Проще говоря, `1`.

Более того, спецификация позиционирует это как "фичу". В шаге *27.a* алгоритма 9.2.12 она говорит, что отдельное Лексическое Окружение для объявлений внутри тела функции создается для того, чтобы замыкания среди формальных параметров не имели доступа к переменным, объявленным внутри тела функции:

> NOTE: A separate Environment Record is needed to ensure that closures
>   created by expressions in the formal parameter list do not have
>   visibility of declarations in the function body.

Именно это в примере, приведенном в вопросе, и происходит. И именно от этого спецификация и пытается нас оградить (хотя польза такой "заботы" довольно спорна, но сейчас не об этом).

Ситуация абсолютно противоположна, когда среди формальных параметров функции нет ни одного параметра по умолчанию:

```js
(function(x) {
    var x = 2;
    var f = () => x;
    console.log(f());
})(1);
```

В этом случае и объявления, сделанные внутри тела функции, и объявления среди формальных параметров относятся к одному и тому же Лексическому Окружению. Поэтому выражение `var x = 2` именно **переопределяет** существующую в этой же области видимости переменную `x`.

Однако если переменная `x` внутри тела функции будет объявлена с использованием ключевого слова `let`, то в таком случае мы получим синтаксическую ошибку:

```js
(function(x) {
    let x = 2;
    var f = () => x;
    console.log(f());
})(1);
```

Связано это с механизмом работы ключевого слова `let`, в частности, что повторное объявление такой переменной недопустимо.

Вообще, это упрощенное объяснение. В некоторых ситуациях даже при использовании ключевого слова `let` (даже при отсутствии параметров по умолчанию среди формальных параметров) все равно будет создаваться новое Лексическое Окружение для таких объявлений. Подробнее об этом в [Приложении B.3.3.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-web-compat-functiondeclarationinstantiation). Однако в рамках этого ответа эти особенности не особо интересны, поэтому я их опущу.

---

И последнее, насчет последнего примера из вопроса:

```js
(function(x, f = () => x) {
    x = 2;
    console.log(f());
})(1)
```

В этом случае ответ `2` обусловлен отсутствием ключевого слова `var`.

Поскольку переменная `x` здесь не *объявляется* в новом Лексическом Окружении (почему новом читай выше), а переопределяет переменную `x`, объявленную в родительском Лексическом Окружении (кстати да, ссылка на внешнее Лексическое Окружение Лексического Окружения, созданного для объявлений внутри тела функции, указывает именно на то Лексическое Окружение, которое существовало до момента создания "дополнительного" Лексического Окружения, см. пункт 27.b), то вызов функции `f` вернет уже переопределенное значение переменной `x`.